# Silverlight Combobox data binding : Basic and quick way?

Tags: silverlight, combobox

Please tell me the basic and quick way to bind a Collection(List,etc) to a combobox and handle the selection changed event and get the selected item.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy. You can do this with XAML+Code or just code. I won't type out a complete solution as I feel you'll benefit more from completing that part yourself. I've assumed here that you already have some XAML declaring a combo box, so I've just shown some code (in C# as you didn't state what language you were using), just know that the event handler could easily be assigned via XAML instead.

```
this.combo.SelectionChanged +=
    new SelectionChangedEventHandler(comboProjects_SelectionChanged);

this.combo.ItemsSource = myCollectionOfItems;
```

This sets up an event handler for the selection changing and also binds the combo to a collection, which it uses to source its items (hence the name, [`ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource(VS.95).aspx)).

Then, in the [`SelectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged(VS.95).aspx) event handler, you can get the [`SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem(VS.95).aspx) property to find out what is selected.

Note that there are some caveats with binding in the [`ComboBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox(VS.95).aspx), so you may find these links useful:

- http://silverlight.net/forums/t/63616.aspx
- http://silverlight.net/forums/p/87111/202335.aspx#202335

Comment: Thanks.. this will also help me... the part where I am really stuck is getting the items displayed in the Combobox.. using the {Binding...} and DisplayMemberPath, etc things... I only get the business object type name in the combo drop down...